# Simple for-loop in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, for-loop, scripting

I have a cvs repository with different modules. The setup is always the same:

```
/data/cvs/<repo>/CVSROOT/passwd
```

I need to have a short script that loops over all repositories and performs this command:

```
grep "^iq" <repo>/CVSROOT/passwd | sort | uniq
```

The purpose is to have all usernames that start with the prefix "iq".
The output will be a list with usernames, passwordhashes and the cvsmodule:

```
iqabcde:5!h8kdh2937slj:cvsabc
```

This output should be split by using ":" as terminator. I need to have 3 variables that I can access.

To be honest I don't have a lot of knowledge in shell scripting. Would be great if anyone could help, because I think this is solvable.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bored.

```
#!/bin/bash
for repo in /data/cvs/*
do
  IFS=: read username hash module < <(grep "^iq" "$repo"/CVSROOT/passwd | sort | uniq)
  echo "Name: $username, Hash: $hash, Module: $module"
done
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. Most of the time I get "Name: , Hash: , Module:" as output. I suppose it is because some password hashes contain special characters? The password hash always contains 13 characters.

Comment: Weird. Which specific lines result in that?

Comment: e.g. hashes like "mE7YHNejLCviM" work, hashes like "JXfFZCZrL.6HY | JW9/ydvBFO482 | 5!b4RlH/IgYzI" don't work.

Comment: can we "hardcode" the password hash to contain exactly 13 characters?

Comment: it works when I use nawk: for repo in /data/cvs/*
do
  grep "^iq" "$repo"/CVSROOT/passwd | sort |uniq | nawk -F ':' '{print "Name: " $1 ", Hash: " $2 ", Module: " $3 }'
done